# Gutenberg richtext block vaildation failed

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I have a problem with understanding richtext elements. I am trying to create form with customizable placeholder and label, but when I save and refresh page i get this error:

```
blocks.min.js?ver=9ed25ffa009c799f99a4340915b6dc6a:3 Block validation: Block validation failed for `kathy/contact-form` ({name: "kathy/contact-form", icon: {…}, keywords: Array(0), attributes: {…}, providesContext: {…}, …}).

Content generated by `save` function:

<form class="wp-block-kathy-contact-form kathyContactForm"><label class="kathyContactFormEmailLabel flexCenterCenter"><span class="kathyContactFormEmailLabelText flexCenterCenter">x</span><input class="kathyContactFormEmail flexCenterCenter" placeholder=""/></label></form>

Content retrieved from post body:

<form class="wp-block-kathy-contact-form kathyContactForm"><label class="kathyContactFormEmailLabel flexCenterCenter"><span class="kathyContactFormEmailLabelText flexCenterCenter">x</span><input class="kathyContactFormEmail flexCenterCenter" placeholder="z"/></label></form>
```

Content is saved and correctly displayed on the site, but editor is showing errors.

My js:

```
registerBlockType('kathy/contact-form', {
    title: 'Kathy Contact Form',
    description: 'Contact form',
    icon: 'format-image',
    category: 'kathy',

    attributes: {
        emailLabel: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'span.kathyContactFormEmailLabelText'
        },
        emailPlaceholder: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'html',
            selector: 'span.kathyContactFormEmail'
        }
    },

    edit: ({attributes, setAttributes}) => {
        const {emailLabel, emailPlaceholder, nameLabel, namePlaceholder,  messageLabel, messagePlaceholder, submitText} = attributes;
        const updateEl = (el, val) => {
            switch(el) {
                case "emailLabel":
                    setAttributes({emailLabel: val});
                    break;
                case "emailPlaceholder":
                    console.log(val)
                    setAttributes({emailPlaceholder: val});
                    break;
            }
        }

        return ([
            <form className={'kathyContactForm'}>
                <label>
                    <RichText className={'kathyContactFormEmailLabelText flexCenterCenter'} key="editable"
                            tagName="span" placeholder="Label text" value={emailLabel}
                            onChange={(val) => updateEl("emailLabel", val)} /> 
                    <RichText className={'kathyContactFormEmail flexCenterCenter'} key="editable"
                            tagName="span" placeholder="Placeholder text" value={emailPlaceholder}
                            onChange={(val) => updateEl("emailPlaceholder", val)} /> 
                </label>
            </form>
        ]);
    },
    save: ({attributes}) => {
        const {emailLabel, emailPlaceholder} = attributes;
        return (
            <form className={'kathyContactForm'}>
                <label className={"kathyContactFormEmailLabel flexCenterCenter"}>
                    <span className={"kathyContactFormEmailLabelText flexCenterCenter"}>{emailLabel}</span>
                    <input className={"kathyContactFormEmail flexCenterCenter"} 
                           placeholder={emailPlaceholder}
                    />
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

I know (or I think I know) error is showed because of span in edit and input in save, but when I replaced span to input in edit and attributes - no error is showed, but updating doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Won't the form and input tags be destroyed when you save by the post content security filters? Even if your block succeeded it'd be stripped out in PHP. There's a reason contact forms don't save form tags directly into the database, and use shortcodes, or dynamically render themselves in PHP. Also your blocks save output differs from what it expected, did you try to create an instance of that block, then changed the block to add an attribute but did not update the content?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Block saves properly, I can see on website my form with input with proper placeholder, but on edit page I see that error when I resfresh or enter edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your block is due to the `selector` value of your `emailPlaceholder` attribute — you set the value to `span.kathyContactFormEmail`, but there's actually no span element with that class in your `save()` function (or the markup/HTML of the element returned by the function).

What you have though, is an input with `kathyContactFormEmail` as the class, so you would need to change the `emailPlaceholder`'s **selector** to `input.kathyContactFormEmail`.

And in addition to that, you should also change the **source** from `html` to `attribute` and set `attribute` to `placeholder` like so:

```js
emailPlaceholder: {
    type: 'string',
    source: 'attribute',      // change it from 'html' to 'attribute'
    attribute: 'placeholder', // add add this
    selector: 'input.kathyContactFormEmail'
}
```

Firstly, because you're using the attribute with the input's placeholder, i.e. `<input placeholder="{ emailPlaceholder }" />`.

And secondly, `input` elements are self-closing, i.e. `<input />` and not `<input></input>`, hence their `innerHTML` value is empty.

So `html` source won't work with inputs because the block editor will read the attribute value from the inner HTML and yet with an `<input />` (or even with `<input>foo</input>` which is invalid..), the editor will get an empty string.

### Additional Issues/Considerations

1. Instead of using a `RichText` element for editing the `emailPlaceholder` attribute, I would use a simple text field, e.g. using [`TextControl`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/text-control/) like so:

   ```js
   <TextControl
       label="Placeholder text"
       value={ emailPlaceholder }
       onChange={ ( val ) => updateEl( 'emailPlaceholder', val ) }
   />
   ```

   PS: Don't forget to import or load the component, e.g. `const { TextControl } = wp.components;`.

   And if you use that component, then you would want to use a `div`, Fragment (`<>` and `</>`) or something other than `label` to wrap the `RichText` and `TextControl` elements, e.g. `<div><RichText .../><TextControl .../></div>`.
2. The `RichText` reference [says](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md#richtextcontent):

   > `RichText.Content` should be used in the `save` function of your block
   > to correctly save rich text content.

   Therefore, instead of `<span className={"kathyContactFormEmailLabelText flexCenterCenter"}>{emailLabel}</span>`, you should do:

   ```js
   <RichText.Content
       tagName="span"
       className="kathyContactFormEmailLabelText flexCenterCenter"
       value={ emailLabel }
   />
   ```
3. For string literals or non-dynamic attribute values, you should just use the `<attribute>="<value>"` syntax, so for example instead of `className={'kathyContactForm'}`, use `className="kathyContactForm"`. That way, your code will become simpler.
4. In your `edit()` function, I don't know why are you returning an array, i.e. `return ([<form>...</form>])`, but you should set a unique [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) prop for each outermost parent element (e.g. if you had `<p><b>foo <i>bar</i></b> baz</p>`, the outermost parent is `p`). So for example, you would do `return ([<form key="your-key">...</form>])`.

   And make sure to use unique keys — the two `RichText` elements in your `edit()` function used the same key ("editable").